# How to read heroku logs?

Tags: python, heroku

Could somebody tell how to read heroku logs?
I mean, when I write `heroku logs --tail` or `heroku logs | grep -i error`, what can I get from that? How to understand the errors I got?
And if there is an article explaining that, I would appreciate it.
I looked for an article about that, and haven't found!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku aggregates several categories of logs, see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging

The application logs are created by your app, you can typically set the level and decide what to log in your code. It is a good idea to catch/log exception.

Error codes generated by Heroku are also useful https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes

Comment: Thank you!  That was useful. I needed to look at the error code after `heroku logs --tail`, and comparing it with the error codes generated by Heroku.